# In Laravel 5.3 when I submit the form all inputs fields are not showing in controller

Tags: laravel-5.3

**Form created in create.blade.php**

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'employees.store', 'class' => 'form', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) !!}
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('name', 'Name:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
        {!! Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('male', 'Male:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
        {!! Form::radio('gender', 'Male', false, ['id' => 'male']) !!}
        {!! Form::label('female', 'Female:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
        {!! Form::radio('gender', 'Female', false, ['id' => 'female']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('dob', 'DOB:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
        {!! Form::date('dob', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('image', 'Image:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
        {!! Form::file('image') !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <strong>Hobbies:</strong><br>
        {!! Form::label('playing', 'Cricket', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
        {!! Form::checkbox('hobbies[]', 'Cricket', false, ['id' => 'playing']) !!}
        {!! Form::label('music', 'Music', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
        {!! Form::checkbox('hobbies[]', 'Music', false, ['id' => 'music']) !!}
        {!! Form::label('travelling', 'Travelling', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
        {!! Form::checkbox('hobbies[]', 'Travelling', false, ['id' => 'travelling']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('email', 'Email:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
        {!! Form::text('email', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('number', 'Number:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
        {!! Form::text('number', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('city', 'City:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
        {!! Form::select('city', ['Bikaner' => 'Bikaner', 'Jaipur' => 'Jaipur', 'Delhi' => 'Delhi'], false, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('address', 'Address:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
        {!! Form::textarea('address', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::submit('Create', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
    </div>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

**Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();
    echo "<pre>";print_R($input);exit;
}
```

When I submit the form with Gender, Image, Hobbies fields as empty then these fields does not appears in the $input in the controller, but when I submit form after filling these fields then it is shown in $input.
So why they don't appear when these fields are empty?